# Pydantic создать модель где используется символ "-"

Tags: python, pydantic

Pydantic создать модель где используется символ `-`. Каким образом это делается?

Пример даты:

```
{"service": "lgd", "sub-forums": "123"}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `alias` в `Field` модели

Пример:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class Model(BaseModel):
    service: str
    sub_forums: int = Field(alias='sub-forums')


m = Model.parse_raw(b'{"service": "lgd", "sub-forums": "123"}')
print(m.sub_forums)
# 123

print(m.dict())
# {'service': 'lgd', 'sub_forums': 123}
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы создать модель с помощью **pydantic**, вам нужно создать класс, наследующий от `BaseModel`, и определить атрибуты модели с помощью аннотаций типа. Например:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    email: str
```

В этом примере у модели `User` есть три атрибута: `id`, `name` и `email`. Каждый атрибут определен с помощью аннотации типа, указывающей тип данных, который ожидается у этого атрибута.

Чтобы создать экземпляр модели, вы можете вызвать конструктор класса, передав в него словарь с данными:

```
data = {
    "id": 123,
    "name": "John Smith",
    "email": "john@example.com",
}

user = User(**data)
```

В этом примере создается экземпляр модели `User` с атрибутами `id`, `name` и `email`, установленными в соответствии с данными из словаря `data`.

Вы можете использовать квадратные скобки `[]` для указания атрибута, использующего символ дефиса:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    service: str
    ["sub-forums"]: str
```

Также можете использовать атрибут `alias` для переименования атрибута с помощью символа дефиса:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    service: str
    sub_forums: str = Field(..., alias="sub-forums")
```

Таким образом вы можете определить модель, использующую символ дефиса. При обработке данных с помощью этой модели вы сможете передать значение атрибута `sub-forums` с помощью ключа `sub_forums`.

Например:

```
model = MyModel({"service": "lgd", "sub_forums": "123"})
assert model.service == "lgd"
assert model["sub-forums"] == "123"
```